# For loop with if else statement not iterating over entire array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have been beating my head agains the wall with a basic JS for loop and if else statement. Unfortunately I can not figure it out so I am kindly seeking you advice.

I have added the code below and this is a link to jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mauro_nappolini/wv5ae1y2/25/#&togetherjs=FFtkmLmEvo

I have an for loop with a nested if else statement which is which does not iterate over the entire array. The for loop stops when the statement returns true and does not iterate over the remaining items in the array.

```
//Loops through and retrieves all emails from a class of jobemail and adds it to an 
array
var allEmails = $(".jobemail").map(function() {
  return this.innerHTML;
}).get();

//Gets the email that we want to use during comapariosion 
let membersEmail = $('.email-comparison').html();

//New array for all matching emails
let newArray = [];
console.log(membersEmail);
console.log(newArray);

//Loops through new array - shows only matching emails and hides emails that do not 
match
for (let i = 0; i < allEmails.length; i++) {
  console.log(allEmails[i]);
  if (allEmails[i] == membersEmail) {
    //Show matching email content container when jobeemail and email-comparison matches
    $(".email-content-container").show();
    newArray.push(allEmails[i])
  } else {
    //Hide matching email content container when jobeemail and email-comparison matches
    $(".email-content-container").hide();

  }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: _"The for loop stops when the statement returns true and does not iterate over the remaining items in the array."_ - not true, the console.log clearly proofs that it iterates over all items. The problem is that you are either showing or hiding _all_ `.email-content-container` elements each time.

Comment: Instead of collecting all the emails as an array of string values and looping over that array, you should loop over `$(".jobemail")` to begin with using https://api.jquery.com/each/, then `$(this)` inside the callback function will give you access to the _current_ `.jobemail` each time, and from there you can easily go up to the parent.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your help!! It is all working perfectly and is very nice and clean compared to my previous code! - https://jsfiddle.net/mauro_nappolini/wv5ae1y2/57/

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is hide all before the loop, and then show the matching ones in the loop

Comment: not necessarily... you can also explicitely hide and show all of them because anyway there's an else condition and the loop goes through all of them The key was collecting the items as html elements instead of their content. I still wonder why my answer was downvoted